# Vaadin 8.1.7 Grid with ComponentRenderer

Tags: java, vaadin8

First of all sorry my poor english.
I have a grid in lazy mode (using data provider) and it has a column contains CheckBox somtimes is visible, sometimse is not, dependent on data.
 When it show the check box columns showing fine but after sorting another column the checkboxes showing mixing.

Where it not should be appear it showing after sorting other column. Data is correct. Here is my code:

```
Grid.Column col = getGrid().addColumn(( EventStorage source ) -> {
    if ( source.getModel().hasDelegate()) {
        source.setVisibleCheckBox(Boolean.FALSE);
        source.setCheckBoxEnable(Boolean.FALSE);
    } else {
        source.setVisibleCheckBox(Boolean.TRUE);
        source.setCheckBoxEnable(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    return source.getCheckBox();
}, new ComponentRenderer());
```

Please give me advice.

Comment: What do you mean by _mixing checkboxes_ is that for example you have 2 columns **A** and **B** with rows respectively **A1 - B1**, **A2 - B2**, **A3 - B3** and after sorting it doesn't match to each other? Like: **A2 - B3** etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use `addComponentColumn()`? So not `addColumn(..)` & `ComponentRenderer`. Like

```
Grid.Column col = getGrid().addComponentColumn(( EventStorage source ) -> {
   if ( source.getModel().hasDelegate()) {
      source.setVisibleCheckBox(Boolean.FALSE);
      source.setCheckBoxEnable(Boolean.FALSE);
   } else {
      source.setVisibleCheckBox(Boolean.TRUE);
      source.setCheckBoxEnable(Boolean.TRUE);
   }
   return source.getCheckBox();
});
```

Comment: IMO the check box should be created within the lambda. If you don't then you create a check box component for each data row beforehand which is a waste of resources :)

Comment: Vaadin team recognize this issue. It is a framework problem.

Comment: @Zaosz Ok, do you have a link to where this issue is described?

Comment: @Zaosz Is it possible to have some images/more detailed description of the problem? 1. I cannot even compile it with `addColumn(..)`, only with `addComponentColumn()` and without `ComponentRenderer`. 2. I cannot see any problem with sorting? So images would greatly help.